# How to get visitor google analytics useing javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have google analytic account i want to get today visitor to show it on my web page how can i do that using JavaScript or asp.net/c#?

i hope there is any snap of code to do that .

Comment: i mean daily visitor counter

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) is well [documented](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/?hl=en).